# Could not insert to database after fetching the column names from the query

Tags: mysql, pdo

I am trying to make the clone of selected table row. The columns are stored in mapping table and are dynamic. I get the column_name from the first query which is to be used in second query to insert the selected result.
In this case I am getting error as Unknown column '$matches'.

```
db = new PDO("...");
$statement = $db->query("select column_name from mapping_table");
$list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
$matches = implode('`,`', $list);

$db1 = new PDO("...");
$db1->query("insert into tbl_user(`$matches`) (SELECT `$matches` FROM tbl_user WHERE id= :id)");
$db1->bindParam(':id', $id);
$result= $db1->execute();
```

Comment: What is the definition of `tbl_users` and what does  `var_dump($matches)` returns?

Comment: @JorgeCampos the column name for table tbl_users are stored in mapping_table. Now from first query I get the column_name "`id`,`name`,`address`,`postal_code`"...

Comment: If it is the same as the columns in tbl_users you just need to remove the backtick from the variable as this `\`$matches\`` it makes the hole list of columns as one single column

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes I already tried removing those backtick

Comment: Although this design makes no sense at all, a table that holds the field names of other table... This is really smelly

Comment: You didn't provide the columns list of the table tbl_users

Comment: yes though smelly but I have no other solution for my requirement

Comment: When I directly use  "insert into tbl_user(id, name, address, postal_code) SELECT m.id, m.name, m.address FROM tbl_user AS m WHERE m.id=5" this is working fine

Comment: Well if you explain the problem and what is the requirement we certainly will give you a better solution than this one for sure. This looks exactly like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: I believe that PDO is the one to blame here in your case. try `insert into tbl_user(" . $matches . ") ...."` same for the select part. PDO must be rewriting your query with single quotes because your variable is a string